# Receiving "package had non-zero exit status" when installing packages on campus Rstudio server?

Tags: r, rstudio-server

I'm trying to install ggplot2 on my campus' Rstudio server. Unfortunately I receive the classic "installation of package 'ggplot2' had non-zero exit status." I've looked through the many threads of users who've had the same problem with other packages, but haven't found any workable solutions.

I've tried using install.packages("ggplot2", dependencies = TRUE), which hasn't worked.

Also, I'm running the most recent version of OSX on a MacBook Pro.

This is the error message I receive:

```
Error: loading failed
Execution halted
ERROR: loading failed
* removing ‘/mnt/trafficstop/jrleary/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.5/vctrs’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘vctrs’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependency ‘vctrs’ is not available for package ‘pillar’
* removing ‘/mnt/trafficstop/jrleary/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.5/pillar’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘pillar’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependency ‘pillar’ is not available for package ‘tibble’
* removing ‘/mnt/trafficstop/jrleary/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.5/tibble’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘tibble’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependency ‘tibble’ is not available for package ‘ggplot2’
* removing ‘/mnt/trafficstop/jrleary/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.5/ggplot2’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘ggplot2’ had non-zero exit status
```

Comment: Without more error messages, it is nearly impossible to give you much guidance.

Comment: Also give us information if you tried to install it on linux or windows or mac os

Comment: In the future, please post the entire console output as the key to your question exists in the log text above what you cut/paste here. One of the dependencies for ggplot failed (looks like it was `vctrs` initially) and that caused everything dependent on that to fail in turn. Resolve whatever the issue was with `vctrs` package and you should be able to install ggplot2.